# ReactJS: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to build a project with Laravel and ReactJs. I have rendered a table and data has been shown. But when I try to use Router in ReactJs to build a CRUD project, it has an error. Could someone help me, please. Here my code, thank you:

My homepage: Example.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {posts: []};
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ posts: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
    postRow(p){
        return (
            <tr key = {p.id}>
                <td>{p.title}</td>
                <td>{p.description}</td>
                <td><a>Edit</a></td>
                <td><a>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
    render() {
        const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => this.postRow(post));
        return (
            <div>
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { posts }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Link to="/add-post">Add</Link>
                //<Route exact path='/add-post' component={CreatePost}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
if (document.getElementById('homepage')) {
    ReactDOM.render(
            <Example />
        , document.getElementById('homepage')
    );
}
```

RoutePath.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import CreatePost from './CreatePost';
import Example from './Example';

export default class RoutePath extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Example}/>
                        <Route exact path='/add-post' component={CreatePost}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

CreatePost.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class CreatePost extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {postTitle: '', postDescription: ''};

        this.titleChange = this.titleChange.bind(this);
        this.descriptionChange = this.descriptionChange.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const post = {
            title: this.state.postTitle,
            description: this.state.postDescription
        }
        let uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add';
        axios.post(uri,post).then((response) => {
            //browserHistory.push('/');
        });
    }
    titleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            postTitle: e.target.value
        })
    }
    descriptionChange(e){
        this.setState({
            postDescription: e.target.value
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
                    <label>Title: </label>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.titleChange}/>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Description: </label>
                    <textarea onChange={this.descriptionChange}></textarea>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="add"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CreatePost;
```

PostController.php

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $post = Post::all();
        return response()->json($post);
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->description = $request->description;
        $post->save();
        return response()->json('Post Added');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the routePath:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; // import BrwoserRouter here
import CreatePost from './CreatePost';
import Example from './Example';

export default class RoutePath extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter> // use it here...
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Example} />
          <Route exact path="/add-post" component={CreatePost} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js (app.js:63198)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/MemoryRouter.js (app.js:62714)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/index.js (app.js:63488)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../resources/js/components/CreatePost.js (app.js:67650)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../resources/js/components/Example.js (app.js:67766)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in RoutePath.js you'll see that you've got your two routes within another route. You need to change this to BrowserRouter. See the docs, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route

This *should* fix your issue.

```
<Route>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Example}/>
      <Route exact path='/add-post' component={CreatePost}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Route>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js (app.js:63198)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/MemoryRouter.js (app.js:62714)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/index.js (app.js:63488)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../resources/js/components/CreatePost.js (app.js:67650)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
 at Module../resources/js/components/Example.js (app.js:67766)
 at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)

Comment: You mean that import ?? I've edited the code above. but it's still the similar error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js
    at __webpack_require__
    at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/MemoryRouter.js (app.js:59710)
    at __webpack_require__ 
    at Module../node_modules/react-router/es/index.js (app.js:60484)
    at __webpack_require__ 
    at Module../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/BrowserRouter.js 
    at __webpack_require__
    at Module../node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js
    at __webpack_require__

Comment: I think the problem is at "import" but i dont know why. I still have installed all library.